# How to read a local database file?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, arraybuffer

I’m trying to read a simple sqlite database. as described [here](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js#loading-a-database-from-a-server)  I need to read a local database file, convert it to Uint8Array and read as readAsArrayBuffer format.

suggested method is XMLHttpRequest as described here. it perfectly worked  but it dosent work in chrome browser.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'DataBaseBackup.db', true);//DataBaseBackup.db is a local file
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function (e) {
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    var db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);
    var contents = db.exec("SELECT * FROM contacts");
    console.log(contents);
    // contents is now [{columns:['col1','col2',...], values:[[first row], [second row], ...]}]
};
xhr.send();
```

how can i read this database file locally?
thanks

Comment: Press F12 and see where and with what error it fails.